# Pass string to JavaScript function results in undefined

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, parameter-passing

So what I am trying to do is very simple and straightforward.
Passing a String to a JavaScript function and print it as following.

```
brightRoom('bedroom');
```

Then

```
function brightRoom(room){
 console.log("bright " . room);
}
```

What I get is undefined. Which I am not sure what may caused that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's concatenation operator is a `+`

```js
brightRoom('bedroom');

function brightRoom(room) {
  // of course console.log("bright " + room); works
  document.write("bright " + room);
}
```

It results in undefined because the JavaScript engine thinks that you are trying to find a property of the string called `room` which of course does not exist. When you try to access a non existent property of an object undefined is returned

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman, no worries, I updated my answer to include why `undefined` is printed, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
brightRoom('bedroom');

function brightRoom(room){
 console.log("bright " + room);
}
```